# how to print a dynamically generated pdf with printJS

Tags: asp.net-core, printjs

[Note this might be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48138874/can-make-print-js-print-a-variable, but I don't know PHP]

I have an ASP.Net core action that creates a PDF on the fly.  I currently have the PDF download to the client, like so:

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Pdf">Download PDF</a>
```

and the controller action

```
public IActionResult Pdf()
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ...
        return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "file.pdf");
    }
}
```

Instead, I would like it to go to the print preview dialog of the browser, for which I was planning to use `printjs`.  But I have to specify a server-based file (such as "docs/file.pdf").  The `printjs` sample is:

```
<button type="button" onclick="printJS('docs/file.pdf')">Print PDF</button>
```

Is there a way to cause the `printJS` file to download the pdf file without needing to save it somewhere?

Comment: Interesting, I know that CanadaPost does this somehow.  I suppose an ajax call can generate the file onto the server's disk somewhere with a unique name and then return that name  to the browser which then uses print.js by asking for that file

Answer (score 0):

Doh.  Too easy:

```
<a onclick="printJS('/home/Pdf')">Print PDF</a>
```

Instead of supplying an href to a file, have the onclick function call printJS with the action name which will execute and download the PDF.